# python 3 JSON wex.nz

Tags: python, json, urlrequest

I have an issue with json on Python3.
I try to get the "pairs" from string of URL: https://wex.nz/api/3/info

This is my code:

```
import urllib.request
import json

url= 'https://wex.nz/api/3/info'
content=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
for line in content:
    liste=json.loads(line)

pairliste=liste['pairs']
print(pairliste)
```

This is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lennart/Documents/Test/Test.py", line 8, in <module>
    liste=json.loads(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 312, in loads
    s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

Comment: What is your error? Why do you not load the response as a single json object?

Comment: Ho can load it into single json? <br/> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lennart/Python/Test/Test.py", line 7, in <module>
    liste=json.loads(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 312, in loads
    s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

Comment: Your traceback should be in the question, not as a comment. You can load the whole thing by getting rid of `for line in content:`. You're iterating the response and then converting to json.

Comment: without the iterating of the response the variable "content" just contains "<http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x7f339875b358>" maybe I am on complete wrong way.

Comment: I would suggest first of all to move to the `requests` library. It is much easier to use, and just call `.json()` on the response.

Comment: Thanks you @roganjosh .

Comment: Did that fix your issue?

Comment: Yes. I am happy. "data =json.loads(content.read().decode())" fix it

Comment: I suggest you post that as an answer to your own question which will show that the question is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to roganjosh.
This fixed my issue:

```
import urllib.request
import json

url= 'https://wex.nz/api/3/info'

content = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

data =json.loads(content.read().decode())
print(data)
```